# Android Webview font scale affected by system font scale settings

Tags: android, html, webview, chromium

**What i want ?**

Disable Webview font scale change by system font scale settings.

**What actually Happens ?**

Webview font scale is affected by system font scale settings.

**eg.** If i set system font scale to small or large then it also affect my android app and HTML inside that webview.
but if system font scale is set to Normal then it working as expected.

Also i have tested that webapp in android chrome and their is no issue with font scale.

**Why i need this ?**

Affecting font scale it also affect Line Height and App layout is looking messy.

**What i have tried ?**

1.Setting font scale in my java code

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.fontScale = 1;
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

And this changes only afftect native layout that is created by XML or JAVA.

Comment: Are you complaining that it is being scaled, or that it isn't?  Your question doesn't make it clear.  The scaling should be done for you by the system, without any effort by you.  If you're trying to turn it off, don't.  This is an accessability setting, and the only way vision impaired users are able to use your app.  Preventing the disabled from using your app is highly immoral, and may be illegal in some locations.

Comment: @GabeSechan i have edited my question. it is more clear.

Comment: Yeah, then the answer is don't.  DOing this will hurt sight impaired people and the disabled.  I have the size pumped up for a reason on my phone-  I actually CANNOT READ your app if I don't.  Do not attempt to circumvent accessability devices needed by the disabled.  If it makes your app slightly less pretty, that's fine-  less pretty but usable is better than illegible.

Comment: Here is font scales 
1. Small = 0.85 ,
2. Normal = 1 ,
3. Medium   = 1.25 ,
4. Large = 1.5 ,



If i set font scale less then normal then it will affect app layout and if i set font scale to normal or greater then normal then it does't affect app layout.

Comment: Yes.  That's on purpose.  People set the font because they LITERALLY CANNOT READ IT with the smaller font sizes.  Do not prevent them from making your app usable.

Comment: Chrome is not allowing font scale change by system settings. so how chrome did this ? i can't found any way for doing this. this would be great help for me.

Comment: My copy of chrome scales with my font, so you're just wrong on that. And once again-  why do you want sight impaired and older people to be unable to use your app?  There is a special place in hell for people who do this kind of thing.

Comment: if pepole can't read then they will increse font size and that doesn't affect app layout. but why people decrease font size ? app layout is looking messy with small font scale.

Comment: also if someone changes settings from accessibility settings then no app can change font size. but if change it from display settings then app can change font size by changing configuration.fontscale or using SP insted of  DP.